# check if the value of one json field is true based on yaml

Tags: python

This is my `yaml`:

```
-
    dedicatedip: 1.1.1.1
    status: active
    type: typeA
-
    dedicatedip: 2.2.2.2
    status: active
    type: typeB
-
    dedicatedip: 2.2.2.2
    status: active
    type: typeA
-
```

This is `json`:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "data": {
    "licenses": [
      {
        "id": 167689,
        "type": "typeA",
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "status": "Active",
        "automated": false,
        "notes": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 167689,
        "type": "typeA",
        "ip": "2.2.2.2",
        "status": "Active",
        "automated": false,
        "notes": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 167689,
        "type": "typeB",
        "ip": "2.2.2.2",
        "status": "Active",
        "automated": true,
        "notes": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to find if the IP in `yaml` has the same type in the `json` (one IP may have different types, and each type is going to be checked separately), and then check the `automated` field in the `json`.

Expected output is:

```
IP 2.2.2.2, type typeA, automated is false.
IP 1.1.1.1, type typeA, automated is false.
```

This is my failed attempt so far:

```
import json, yaml

with open ("file.yaml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as yf, open("file.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as jf:
    ydata = list(yaml.safe_load_all(yf))
    jdata = json.load(jf)
    delta = [
        (yd["dedicatedip"], jd["type"], yd["status"], jd["status"])
        for yd in ydata[0] for jd in jdata["data"]["licenses"]
        if yd and yd["dedicatedip"] == jd["ip"]
        and yd["type"].replace("Type ", "").lower() == jd["type"].lower()
        and jd["automated"] != 'true'
    ]


for vars in delta:
    print('IP {}, license type {} automate is false in json.\n'.format(*vars))
```

I get this output when I run, which is not correct:

```
IP 1.1.1.1, license type typeA, automate is false is json.
IP 2.2.2.2, license type typeB, automate is false is json.
IP 2.2.2.2, license type typeA, automate is false is json.
```

Comment: this code ran fine for me (after fixing the missing quote for the yaml file)

Comment: @Xnot thanks, I see it runs:( but prints all of them, both trues and falses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jd["automated"]` is a bool not a string, so you should be using `and not jd["automated"]` instead of `and jd["automated"] != 'true'` in the condition.

Comment: Thanks, I tried like `!= True` or `== False` but they didn't work either. I mean the boolean true/false.